# How to question user in forward chainig expert system

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I have to create an expert system in the medical field, I decided to use forward chaining starting from a set of facts, and then I have to deduce new information and the final diagnosis also by questioning the user. But how do I interrogate the user?
I suppose I must first start the inferential process to analyze the first facts in the knowledge base, then interrogate the user and restart the inferential process.
I can't understand how to combine these things

Comment: There are a few of these type `expert system in the medical field` answered with the tag [tag:Prolog]. Please search for them and note why they don't answer your problem.

Comment: Is this an exercise for a Mycin-like expert system to be written in Prolog? At the risk of creating confusion, take a short look at "Constraint Handling Rules" to see if that shoe fits better than Prolog itself. (There are also the direct descendant of forward-chaining, CLIPS, Jess and Drools, and each with their specificities.) Don't forget to look at [Bayesian Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) which [solve the brittle ad-hocery of Mycin et al.](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/probabilistic-graphical-models/application-medical-diagnosis-A2D3n). Ready for a PhD!

Answer (score 0):

In forward chaining languages that support the assignment of priorities to rules, it can be as simple as assigning lower priorities to rules that ask questions and designing them so that questions aren't asked about information that's already been deduced.